# jquery 1.8.0, jquery ui included?

Tags: jquery

On jsfiddle.net, when I select jQuery 1.7.2, a drop down menu opens giving me the opportunity to select jQuery UI to include.  However, when I select jQuery 1.8.0, it doesn't do that, so I assumed that jQuery UI was now built into jQuery. However, this fiddle doesn't work with jQuery 1.8.0 selected, but it does work with 1.7.2 and jQuery UI included

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/sTzCS/

I'm basically just trying to play around with the sortable() function of JQuery UI, that would let me drag list elements into different positions after with jQuery realigning everything in the list after the drag.  Here's a working fiddle with jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI included http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/sTzCS/2/

```
   <ul id="sortlist">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: I don't think jquery 1.8.0 includes its ui addin. It's just that Jsfiddle does not provide an option for jquery ui for 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI is not built into jQuery. jsFiddle has not updated their list. Just keep in mind that jQuery 1.8+ requires jQuery UI 1.8.22+.